# Mongo: Grouping top traffic keywords

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of mongo documents (every day a different one) sharing the following format:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "start-date" : ISODate("2013-11-24T00:00:00Z"),
        "end-date" : ISODate("2013-11-24T00:00:00Z"),
        "dimensions" : "ga:keyword",
        "metrics" : [
            "ga:organicSearches"
        ],
    },
    "totalResults" : 3,
    "totalsForAllResults" : {
        "ga:organicSearches" : 22
    },
    "rows" : [
        [
            "Paradise",
            18
        ],
        [
            "vacations",
            1
        ],
        [
            "vacation rentals",
            3
        ]
    ],
    "query_id" : 1,
}
```

So, each day (start-date) can contains the same or different (rows) keywords and values.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "start-date" : ISODate("2013-11-25T00:00:00Z"),
        "end-date" : ISODate("2013-11-25T00:00:00Z"),
        "dimensions" : "ga:keyword",
        "metrics" : [
            "ga:organicSearches"
        ],
    },
    "totalResults" : 3,
    "totalsForAllResults" : {
        "ga:organicSearches" : 22
    },
    "rows" : [
        [
            "paradise",
            20
        ],
        [
            "vacations",
            3
        ],
        [
            "relax is monday",
            8
        ]
    ],
    "query_id" : 1,
}
```

I was reading a lot about unwind, match, group and sort. Buuut honestly, I'm too far from finding an elegant solution.

Using aggregate framework: I was wondering how to get the top traffic keywords in any particular date range (where the keywords and the amount of keywords can vary from one day to the other)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify why exactly do we need to do your job if even you do not want to do it?

Comment: Thanks Salvador and Andrew, in that time was very hard for me to get into Aggregate Framework, next time I will be acting according to question checklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With schema like this it will be hard to find neat solution. When using aggregation framework you cannot access elements of array by index so you'll have to unwind twice to access individual keyword and count. You can try with pipeline similar to this:

```js
pipeline = [
    // Filter by date
    {
        "$match" : {
            "query.start-date" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            },
            "query.end-date" : {
                "$lte" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    },
    // Unwind rows array 
    {
        "$unwind" : "$rows"
    },
    // Keep keyword-count as a key for second unwind
    {
        "$project" : {
            "rows" : 1,
            "keyword" : "$rows"
        }
    },
    // Unwind once again to get count and keyword document
    {
        "$unwind" : "$rows"
    },
    // I am not sure it is required but to be sure we sort documents
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "keyword" : 1,
            "rows" : -1
        }
    },
    // Group to extract keyword-count pairs
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "i" : "$id",
                "k" : "$keyword"
            },
            "keyword" : {
                "$first" : "$rows"
            },
            "count" : {
                "$last" : "$rows"
            }
        }
    },
    // Final grouping
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$keyword",
            "count" : {
                "$sum" : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
]
db.foo.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: It works very very very cool! You are great zero323!!!

Comment: Hi @zero323! I was wondering about any suggestion to improve performace with this kind of query, where should be needed to add indexes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally indices can be used only at the beginning of the pipeline before any `$project`, `$unwind`, and `$group` operator. In your case you it means only the first match so you don't have much of a choice. I would try compound index on `query.start-date` and `query.end-date`.

Comment: If changing schema is an option one thing you can try is to replacing nested arrays in rows with subdocuments for example this way:

`"rows" : [
        {
            "k": "paradise",
            "v": 20
        },
        {
            "k": "vacations",
            "v": 3
        },
        {
            "k": "relax is monday",
            "v": 8
        }
    ]`

With schema like this your pipeline can be much simpler (`$match`, `$unwind`, `$group`) and whole operation should be faster.